# How do I get a vector that faces away from (perpendicular from ) arbitrary terrain

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image: Diagram]

Like the image above, I want to place an object so that it faces away from the surface( I am using graphics instancing to create grass). I assume this will have to do something with the surface normals/ raycasting, but I can not figure out how to do it. I'm using unity and c# so answers relating to that would be great.

I haven't really been able to get off my feet with this problem, but I've tried rotating it so that it faces up always, but that results in a lot of clipping and weird behavior.

Comment: You can raycast down onto the surface at the point you are interested in, and the `RaycastHit.normal` will include the surface normal. Then you can pass that normal to `Quaternion.LookRotation` or some similar function, and voila.

Comment: How are you drawing the terrain? It may influence the best method.

Comment: thats kind of what i was thinking, but since im instancing many thousands of grass objects on the gpu, im worried using raycasts for all of them would tank performance

Answer (score 0):

Complicated problem of which Unity already has a solution. Here is a script to automatically align it to the normal. I've also added a LayerMask option so you only hit the correct layer on your check as well as a max height value. Remember to set both from the Inspector.

```
public class NormalRotation : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float maxHeight = 2f;
    public LayerMask layer;
        
    void Update() => RotateTransformToNormal();
    
    void RotateTransformToNormal() => 
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(transform.up, GetNormal()) * transform.rotation;
    
    Vector3 GetNormal()
    {
        // Raycast down from the transform
        Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, Vector3.down);
        RaycastHit hit;
        
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, maxHeight, layer))
        {
            return hit.normal;
        }
        
        return transform.up;
    }
}
```